Android端末にてLINEアプリ内ブラウザでのLINEログイン時の認証ができない
LINE内ブラウザでLINEログインをしてもらうToC向けのサービスの開発を行っております。
以下事象の解消の仕方がわからずに困っています。
もし解決方法をご存知の方がいましたらぜひ教えていただけますと幸いです。
事象
Android端末にてLINEアプリ内ブラウザでのLINEログイン時の認証ができず、ログインが成功せず、エラーになってしまう
詳細仕様

認証基盤はAWSのCognitoを利用
OpenID ConnectでLINEログインとCognito連携をしている
認証画面はAmplify SDKのAuthenticationで開発https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/

事象の補足

Cognito側にユーザーは作成されていなかった
クライアント側にエラーはでていなかった
LINE内部ブラウザ以外のブラウザだと認証できる（Chrome、Safari）
iPhoneでは問題なく動いている
LINE内ブラウザはデバッグができずエラーメッセージが見れないため検証ができずにいる

その他
もし解消しなければLINE内ブラウザを使わないやり方を検討する必要
